# how to solve 404 error on hosted web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

hi am new to jquery mobile and web api and am currently working on a project that uses both. I have hosted the application in my IIS7 the problem i am unable to access my controller and i always get a 404 error when i try to do that. On my development machine it works fine. i have looked at some of the answers on stack over flow non of them seem to be working.Any help plz

see code below

WebApiConfig.cs

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

my controller

```
public class ManufacturerController : ApiController
{
    private List<Manufacturer> manufacturers = new List<Manufacturer>();
public ManufacturerController()
    {

        manufacturers.Add(new Manufacturer(1, "AUDI"));
        manufacturers.Add(new Manufacturer(2, "BMW"));
        manufacturers.Add(new Manufacturer(3, "MAZDA"));
        manufacturers.Add(new Manufacturer(4, "NISSAN"));
        manufacturers.Add(new Manufacturer(5, "FORD"));
}

public IEnumerable<Manufacturer> GetManufacturers(string manufacturerSearch)
  {
      var _products = manufacturers.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(manufacturerSearch.ToUpper()));


            return _products;

    }
```

my Jquery mobile autocomplete code

```
(document).on("pageinit", function () {

//manufacturer search
$("#manufacturer").on("listviewbeforefilter", function (e, data) {
    var $ul = $(this),
        $input = $(data.input),
        value = $input.val(),
        html = "";
    $ul.html("");
    if (value && value.length > 0) {
        $ul.listview("refresh");
        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function() {
                $ul.html('<h4>Loading...</h4>');
            },
            url: "http://my_server/api/manufacturer/?manufacturerSearch=" + value,
            //timeout: 3000,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: {
                q: $input.val()
            },
            error: function (xhr, errorType) {
                //if (errorType === "error") {
                    //showError(xhr.status, xhr.statusText);
                //$input.val("");
                alert("Error: " + xhr.status + "," + xhr.statusText);
                //}
            }
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            $.each(response, function (i, val) {
                html += "<li id='" + val.Id + "'>" + val.Name + "</li>";
            });
            $ul.html(html);
            $ul.listview("refresh");
            $ul.trigger("updatelayout");
            $ul.find('li').on("click", function () {
                $input.val($(this).text());
                selectedManufacturerId = getId(this);
                $("#manufacturer").empty();
            });
        });
    }
});
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

With Visual Studio, you will typically use a URI like this - `http://localhost:<port>/api/manufacturer`. When you deploy this in IIS, removing the port and changing the host name will not be enough. You will have you app deployed in IIS as an app. This will be generally your project name. So, the right URI will be `http://myserver/myapp/api/manufacturer`.